# django: fields of a model mixin dynamically created does not appear in ModelForm

Tags: django

I'm trying to generate a model mixin dynamically.

I'm having a problem to see the fields when I use a ModelForm but otherwise the fields exist 
in the final Model.

```
def create_address_fields_mixin(prefix='', fields_kwargs={}):

    class AddressFieldsModelMixin(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            abstract = True

    fields = {
        'address_line_1': (AddressLineModelField, {'editable': True}),
        'address_line_2': (AddressLineModelField, {'blank':True, 'null':True}),
        'city': (CityModelField, {}),
        'state': (USStateModelField, {}),
        'zipcode': (USZipCodeModelField, {})
    }

    for field_name, (field_klass, kwargs) in fields.iteritems():

        name = '{}{}'.format(prefix, field_name)
        kwargs.update( fields_kwargs.get(field_name, {}) )

        setattr(
            AddressFieldsModelMixin,
            name,
            field_klass(**kwargs)
        )

    return AddressFieldsModelMixin


AddressModelMixin = create_address_fields_mixin(prefix='main_')

class User(AddressModelMixin, TimeStampedModel):
    pass
```

Creating a model and accessing the fields work:

```
u = User()
u.main_address_line_1 # works
```

But when using a ModelForm, the fields does not seem to exist:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = User

f = UserForm()
f.fields # the fields from the model mixin do not exist
```

How ModelForm finds the fields of the model?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should always explicitly list fields in your ModelForm as its done in [DjangoDocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).

So this might help:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Please add some description while answering.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It does not work. I also tried to explicitely list the fields but it sill does not work.

I think I understood where the problem is. Even though ``u.main_address_line_1`` works, the fields does not seem to really "be part of" the model. In the init method of ``django.db.models.base.Model``, it looks like it iters through the fields using ``self._meta.fields`` or ``self._meta_concrete_fields``. I do not understand how django handles the fields but the fields of my Mixin are not in either of those... I do not know why my fields are not added normally.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution.
The problem was the way I was dynamically creating the model. The fields were not really added to the model.

Here is the solution so that it might help someone who encounters the same problem:

```
def create_model_mixin(model_name, model_base, model_definition, fields_prefix='', fields_kwargs={}):
     # Build the class attributes
    attrs = {}
    attrs['__module__'] = __name__

    # Create the relevant meta information
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    attrs['Meta'] = Meta

    # Build the model by adding django database Field subclasses to the attrs dict
    for field_name, field_klass, kwargs in model_definition['fields']:
        name = '{}{}'.format(fields_prefix, field_name)
        kwargs.update( fields_kwargs.get(field_name, {}) )
        attrs[name] = field_klass(**kwargs)

    # Create the new model class
    model_class = type(model_name, (model_base,), attrs)

    return model_class
```

And you can use it this way:

```
model_name = 'AddressModelMixin'
model_base = models.Model
model_definition = {
    'fields': [
        ('address_line_1', AddressLineModelField, {}),
        ('address_line_2', AddressLineModelField, {'blank':True, 'null':True}),
        ('city', CityModelField, {}),
        ('state', USStateModelField, {}),
        ('zipcode', USZipCodeModelField, {})
    ]
}

model_class = create_model_mixin(model_name, model_base, model_definition, fields_prefix='my_prefix')
```